# How to get field values using Guzzle?

Tags: php, guzzle

I need to scrap some data from url using Guzzle so I am using this code:

```
<?php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';
  use GuzzleHttp\Client;

  function placeholder($someParam)
  {
    $client = new Client([
      'base_uri' => 'http://archive-grbj-2.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/',
      'timeout'  => 5.0,
    ]);

    # Request / or root
    $response = $client->request('GET', '/');
    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    print_r($body);

  }

?>
```

but how I can return some fields value for all articles, like Article Title, Article Date, Author Name in JSON format ?

Comment: You would have to parse the HTML, which is a huge pain and likely to be unreliable. A better bet would be to look for an RSS feed on the newspaper site.

Comment: Like [this](http://www.grbj.com/rss/8) one.

Comment: What does that return? I haven't used guzzle in a while. But I would think you can just json_encode() the returned content if you wanted it to be JSON? You of course need to parse through it. But after you var_dump the contents you should be pretty familiar with the structure..

Comment: yes I need to parse the HTML, any example how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Guzzle is a tool for HTTP communication, but you need a more high level tool, a page **scraper** . They have specific methods to extract content from the page.

There are some for PHP, the simplest is [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte). It has some examples already on GitHub, also you can search SO (there are many answers about it already).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the Symfony DomCrawler and CssSelector component. That way you can just use css selectors to get the items you need from the page.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function to parse the html. The first argument of this function is a regular expression that should match the content you are interested in